# "/" parameter in function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep seeing functions like

```
async def coro(self, a, b, /) -> None:
    ...
```

What does the / at the end mean?

I've googled "/" in python, "/" in function parameters in python and a few other things and i just cant find an answer, so what does it do?

Comment: I'm curious how you tried researching this question before asking? A useful tip is to use `site:stackoverflow.com` when Googling to search just StackOverflow. Using the query `site:stackoverflow.com python slash in arguments`, the first 5 hits are all direct answers to this question.

Comment: It's described in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).  Specifically:  *Changed in version 3.8: The / function parameter syntax may be used to indicate positional-only parameters. See PEP 570 for details.*

Comment: @Brian61354270 I think its because I used "/" instead of "slash"